# Computing entropy of weight matrix of artificial neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, entropy, information-theory

Has anyone come across a way of computing the entropy of the weight matrix of a multi-layer perceptron?

Answer (score 0):

evaluate the weight matrix of multi-layer perceptron then calculate entropy of that matrix.

One way to do that can be Von Neumann entropy of a matrix. you can find the general overview at [wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy)  You can also look for its optimization [here.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13522/constrainted-optimization-problem-in-matrix-entropy)

EDIT:
Shannons entropy is a special case of Von Neumann entropy. Start with [Shannons entropy](https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2012/12/16/calculating-the-entropy-of-data-in-a-table-or-matrix/) which is easy to understand and most likely to fit your needs.

Comment: in terms of CS von neumann entropy is quite abstract object, you will actually end up simply with Shannons entropy, which is a better thing to point someone new to the field at.